# Prevent view invalidation when route changes in SAPUI5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a page with a route `#grants/{grantId}` that contains tabbed content. I want each tab to be accessible by route `#grants/{grantId}/{tabId}`.

So I've setup router like below and i works, however when I switch tabs (e.g. when i go from `#grants/123/tab1` to `#gratns/123/tab2`) the conent of the page gets rebuild (invalidated). How can I prevent that?

```
var oRouter = new sap.ui.core.routing.Router([
{
    pattern: "grants",
    name: "_grants",
    view: "grants.Grants",
    viewType: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.HTML,
    viewId: "grants",
    targetControl: "theContent",
    targetAggregation: "content",
    clearTarget: true,
    subroutes: [
    {
        pattern: "grants/{id}/:period:",
        name: "_grantPortfolio",
        view: "grants.GrantPortfolio",
        viewType: sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.HTML,
        viewId: "grantPortfolio",
        targetControl: "theContent",
        targetAggregation: "content",
        clearTarget: true
    }]
}]);
```

Comment: What is a view invalidation?

Comment: @matbtt view gets reloaded (or refreshed), as if we are navigation to another page

Comment: What do you expect, you're a navigating to another route?! What is the difference between #grants/123 and #grants/123/periods?

Comment: @matbtt I expect the view to not refresh as in fact we are not navigating to another route. There's no difference between `#grants/123` and `#grants/123/periods` as these are just 2 matches for the pattern `grants/{id}/:period:`

Comment: Changing the hash by appending something is handled as a navigation. Please explain what you are doing (with code example), then it is easier to help.

Comment: @matbtt thans for your efforts, updated the question!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question I would suggest to implement a special logic in your controller's route match callback. There you can check - depending on the event parameter - which data needs to be loaded and which data have been loaded already. For more specific hints a running example would be required.